# Chain queries in parent Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a bunch of different Models that access different tables in a database and are chained to each other by inheritance as follows:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    # Some unique fields and properties

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True # Inherited by two "food groups" with different tables


class FoodGroup(Food):
    # Some unique fields and properties

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'foodgroup'

class Fruit(FoodGroup):
    # Some unique fields and properties

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fruit'


class Apple(Fruit):
    # Some unique fields and properties

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'apple'


class Seed(Apple):
    # This is a placeholder to collect all of the data
    # under a name that makes sense rather than just "Apple"

    # One unique field

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        managed = False # Doesn't have a table
```

I would like to be able to create an instance of the `Seed` class that then has all of the parent class fields from their respective tables and allows me to access it simply through the one `Seed` object. The issue is that I need data from the fields in the `Food` class for the queries in the `Fruit`, and `Apple` classes.

How can I run all of the queries in each of the parent classes, from Food to Apple in order and assign it to one variable?

I can call `objects.get()` for one specific parent class using

```
seed = Seed._meta.get_parent_list()[2].objects.get(name=name)
```

but how can I call all of the queries together?

Thank you in advance.

**Edits/Additions:**

In the comments below, Daniel Roseman suggested using ForeignKeys instead of inheritance. So the new setup would be something like this:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    # Some unique fields and properties
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True # Inherited by two "food groups" with different tables

class FoodGroup(Food):
    apples = models.ForeignKey(
          'Apples',
          on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

If the Apples class is

```
class Apples(models.Model):
    @cached_property
    def apples():
        return Apples.objects.filter(Q(color__contains=color) | Q(name__contains=name))
```

where `color` and `name` are from the "Food" class, how can I access the `apples` property in `FoodGroup` and the `color` and `name` fields in `Apples`?

Comment: But you can access the fields of the parent models on the `Seed` instance. And you can also use the  parent fields in queries à la `Seed.objects.get(foo="bar")` even if `foo` is a field in the `Fruit` table.

Comment: Why are you using inheritance here? It doesn't seem like the right tool; standard ForeignKeys would be better.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you have an example of how I would use ForeignKeys for a different table/Model? Just using ForeignKey causes me to get an `Unknown column `food.apple_id` in 'field list'` error. It seems like need to use GenericForeignKey with the contenttype framework, but the documentation is slightly unclear on the outcome of it.

Comment: No, you don't need generic foreign keys, you need actual foreign keys. Examples are in the tutorial.